# generating a random number and send to the header

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

In my login form, if email or password is wrong I set `header ('Location: login.php?Err=284613');`. Then using Javascript I capture it and give the error code to the page using `if (window.location.search == "?Err=284613"){}`.

The issue is that I don't want the user to type `login.php?Err=284613` and trigger the error code manually.

Can I generate random numbers with PHP and show different numbers each time in `login.php?Err="random numbers"`. Of course, then I need to capture that random number with javascript in order to show the error on the page.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
{
    exit('Please fill both the username and password fields!');
}

if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, Password FROM users WHERE Email = ?'))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password))
        {

            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            header('Location: index.php');

        }
        else
        {

            header('Location: login.php?Err=284613');

        }
    }
    else
    {

        header('Location: login.php?Err=284613');

    }

    $stmt->close();
}
}

?>
```

```js
    
if(window.location.search == "?Err=284613")
{
    
 setError(email, 'Wrong Password!');
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you need a Random number or do you need a Unique number? Also do you want to do this in PHP or in JavaScript?

Comment: Unique number. with php i need to write it to the header and detect it with javascript

Comment: actually unique or random doesn't matter

Comment: Why not simply use AJAX in JavaScript, POST the login / password, and get a Success or Error response. Then the javascript can alert the user without having to worry about a Unique number.

Comment: 'cause idk ajax. I did a look but that's so complicated

Comment: can you make the php code work with ajax

Comment: You can get best answer here for your problem https://fellowtuts.com/jquery/get-query-string-values-url-parameters-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following HTML / jQuery code.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".login").submit(function(event) {
    var user = $(".login #username").val();
    var pass = $(".login #password").val();
    var valid = (user !== "") && (pass !== "");
    if (valid) {
      $.post($(this).attr("action"), {
        username: user,
        password: pass
      }, function(results) {
        if (results.error == false) {
          window.location.href = "index.php";
        } else {
          alert(results.message);
          return false;
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert("Login and Password must be entered.");
      return false;
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.login ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.login ul li label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="login" action="login.php" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="username">Login:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" value="jsmith@smithco.com" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" value="Peaches!nAcan" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button class="login-btn" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

This is an example of a very basic Login form and very basic validation. When the Form is submitted, either by button click or the User hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, an AJAX Post is sent to PHP with the Username and Password.

In your PHP, login.php, file, you might have something like:

```
<?php
$results['error'] = False;
header('Content-type: application/json');
if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
  $results['error'] = True;
  $results['message'] = 'Please fill both the username and password fields!';
  echo json_encode($results);
  exit(0);
}
// Prepare connection to SQL for Select Query
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, Password FROM users WHERE Email = ?')) {
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
    $stmt->fetch();
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
      session_regenerate_id();
      $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
      $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
      $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
      echo json_encode($results);
    } else {
      $results['error'] = True;
      $results['message'] = "Incorrect Login or Password.";
      echo json_encode($results);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    exit(0);
  }
}
?>
```

It may seem redundant to check everything again, yet if a bad actor tries to bypass your Login Script or navigates directly to the page; they will encounter an error (in JSON). Also this assumes that `index.php` is looking for a valid Session.

Also if there is an error in SQL you can relay this back to the AJAX too. Something like "There was a lookup failure, please try again." Basically, this is a small script that returns some JSON data, so it is now more like an API. You Post data to it, and it gives you a JSON response. This makes AJAX requests very easy.

When the data is posted, if there is no Error, the initial `False` is returned to the AJAX Request and the script handles this by redirecting the browser to the new page. If it is changed to `True`, the message is passed back to the AJAX request and it displays the message.

See More:

- https://alistapart.com/article/prettyaccessibleforms/
- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: i'll try thank you man <3